# combine date and time of two fields then insert into third field of table

Tags: php, mysql

I have `tbl1` which has field `date` and `time`.Suppose there's another table `tbl2` with field `date_time`.Now,I want to take data from `date` & `time` field of `tbl1`,combine them and insert to `date_time` field of `tbl2`,in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format or which ever format possible.Please some one help,inserting from one table to another isn't a problem but combining value of two field then inserting to another table is making me headache?

Comment: What is the relation between these tables?

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate the date and time field from tbl1.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (datetime_field) 
VALUES (SELECT CONCAT(date_filed, ' ', time_field) 
        FROM tbl1 WHERE pk_field = your_condition);
```

Notice: The sub-select must return only one result!

Answer (score 1):

```
  INSERT INTO tbl2 (date_time)  
  SELECT CONCAT(`date`, ' ', `time`)
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE your_condition
```